# Zend 1.10 'isPost' returns false when Af Networking 2.2 posts to it

Tags: ios, http, zend-framework, post, afnetworking-2

I have an iOS7 AF Networking 2.2 based application. In it I am posting to a Rest API that I also maintain based off Zend framework 1.10. 
When I make this request in the App:

```
     //create request 
   NSString *url = @"https://url.tosendto.com";
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"email":email,@"graph_id":graphId };
  //Build request manager
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:[self key] forHTTPHeaderField:@"key"];
  //FIRE!
    [manager POST:url parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         NSLog(@" %@ ",operation.responseString);
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@" %@ ",operation.responseString);
     }];
```

It fires off a proper request however on the server Zend's
 `$this->getRequest()->isPost();`always returns false, the same post works fine in ASIHTTPRequest. 
Help! I've tried everything! All other methods (Get, Put, Delete, etc) work fine!

Comment: I'm not an ios developer, but that sure looks like a GET in your code example.

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that,Let me edit it to what the actual function is. This was a bit of test code with all the proprietary stuff ripped out, not the actual function that was failing (as a POST). Thanks!

Comment: Probably worth checking the access log on your server to confirm what request method is actually being used, to narrow this down to a problem with your ios code or ZF. `isPost()` just checks `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`.

Comment: Also keep an eye out for redirects, just in case the POST is being redirected to another URL, leading to a GET. Unlikely but not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, of course it was an amateur mistake!
So, example.com and www.example.com are different things. 
In our case www.example.com redirects to example.com, in that case the post data is lost and the api sees it as a get! Silly mistake but kinda funny. Hopefully it will help someone else!